# Probability of at least one of my cards getting picked

Tags: probability

Here is the scenario:

There are is a lottery event in which there a certain number of participants and I'm one of them. All participants can submit one or more cards. After everybody including me put our cards into the deck, the total number of cards in the deck will be `n`. All cards are uniquely numbered from 1 to `n`. Out of these `n` cards, `m` cards are my cards. `m` is at least 1 and utmost `n` (obviously). Now, `k` cards are picked out of these `n` cards in random.

**What is the probability that at least one of my cards gets picked up? (an equation with `m`, `n` and `k`)**

Example 1:
There are 1000 cards of which 1 card is mine. 500 cards get picked randomly. 
=> Probability of at least one of my cards getting picked is **0.5**

Example 2:
There are 100 cards of which 51 cards are mine. 50 cards get picked randomly. 
=> Probability of at least one of my cards getting picked is **1.0**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it like this:

$$ p(A)=\frac{ \binom {n-m} {k}}{\binom {n}{k}}$$

Cards on the table - $n$, your cards $m$, number of cards on the table that aren't yours $n-m$, so we pull out $k$ cards from $n$ on the table, and event A is the one when none of your cards gets pulled out so we pull out $k$ cards from $n-m$  cards that aren't yours.

A - none of your cards gets pulled out, inverse event is that at least one of your cards gets pulled out (B) so:

$$p(B)=1-p(A)=1-\frac{ \binom {n-m} {k}}{\binom {n}{k}}$$

If "none of my cards pulled out" is false then "at least one of my cards is pulled out" must be true!